# About Promises and returning a type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

This is my first week with TS after two years coding with Clojure, so far it has being a fun trip but today I found a "loop" from which I can not escape.

I have an interface:

```
interface ICustomer {
  id: number,
  first_name: string
 }
```

I want a function to consume an API, get the customer and return the interface but as far as I understand, an "async" function like:

```
async consultApi( id: number ): Promise<any> {
  const customer = await SomeExternalApi.getCustomer(id);
}
```

will ALWAYS return a promise. As suspected, I don't want a promise, I want the hash-like object from the "SomeExternalApi.getCustomer" method, so I need another async function to "resolve" the promise:

```
async getCustomer( id: number ): Promise<any> {
  const customer = await consultApi(id: number );
}
```

but again, a sync function will ALWAYS return a promise, not my now long yearned for customer data.

How can I do a function like:

```
getCustomer( id: number ): ICustomer {
  const customer = consultApi(id: number );
}
```

to get out of the "loop" ?.

I could try avoiding all the "async" functions and write something like:

```
return Promise.then(response => response.json)
```

in a non-async function, but I bet the problem is my lack of expertise with TS. Anyhow, how TS developers use "async" functions to get the "resolved" data and return a fulfilled Interface and not a Promise?

Comment: The reason you want to return a promise is that you don't want the code to block while waiting on the result (javascript has but 1 thread) and there is no gaurentee when the result will be retuned from the asynchronous call.

Comment: Read through the suggested duplicate's answer, it should clear it up for you.

Comment: JavaScript functions always return immediately, synchronously. If you want a function to wait for some I/O or anything like that then you want it to return a Promise (or accept a callback); the only alternative is a spinlock which blocks the event loop and all other code from running. So you're correct that you can't make the function return anything other than a Promise, but what else would you have it return immediately before the I/O is done?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible for an async function to return anything other than a promise. Calling to an API and getting a result is and asynchronous action, and so it requires asynchronous action.

```
return Promise.then(response => response.json)
```

will not help you either. You can call `then()` on a promise (not the `Promise` constructor) to indicate an action that should be executed after the promise is resolved, but the return value of this is also a promise.

At the time an API request is made, the result has not yet been sent, therefore it is not possible to immediately return the result.

Comment: yep, async code requires handling it asynchronously. Spin loops don't work either, as javascript won't check if there is an async response until all currently executing functions have returned. (And a spin loop by definition never returns). So you have to shift your state of mind to async.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Spinlocks can work, they just have to synchronously poll for some state change (EG. fs.readFileSync) instead of relying on an async callback to have run. They are pretty much always a bad idea in JavaScript since they block the whole event loop, but they can be used.

Comment: I meant a spin loop that checked internal javascript state change (such as if an async callback had changed a global variable), not external state change (such as if a file had changed), but good point.